# Is it possible to extend "kubectl create"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

From "Extending kubectl with plugins":

> It is currently not possible to create plugins that overwrite existing
> `kubectl` commands. [...] Due to this limitation, it is also not
> possible to use plugins to add new subcommands to existing `kubectl`
> commands. For example, adding a subcommand `kubectl create foo` by
> naming your plugin `kubectl-create-foo` will cause that plugin to be
> ignored.
>
> -- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/#limitations

Is there another way to extend `kubectl create`?

Comment: Well, you answered(the official documentation) the question.  you might need to tweak your approach a bit. Care to share what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can just use a script, why use it as a plugin? anyway, plugins are local to the client machine so is any other script.

Comment: it is not extensible via kubectl plugins, but I was looking if there maybe is another way to add an "generator"(?) to `kubectl create`. I checked the source, it really seems kubectl create subcommands are hardcoded :(

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like that in source code, all sub-commands are currently registered explicitly ([cf.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/db8d77cfeb0593b0accc17804df43834cc7f9917/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/create/create.go#L142-L160)):

```golang
    // create subcommands
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateNamespace(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateQuota(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateSecret(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateConfigMap(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateServiceAccount(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateService(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateDeployment(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateClusterRole(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateClusterRoleBinding(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateRole(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateRoleBinding(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreatePodDisruptionBudget(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreatePriorityClass(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateJob(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateCronJob(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateIngress(f, ioStreams))
    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdCreateToken(f, ioStreams))
    return cmd
```